# Coin tossing simulation unexpected probabilities

Tags: python, simulation, coin-flipping

This is a script I wrote to simulate a coin toss game that ends in a given fixed sequence of outcomes (tosses are either ones or zeroes). This fixed sequence characterizes the game. For example, `coin_series('01'`) simulates a series of tosses that culminate in a `0` followed by a `1`; valid outcomes are `x01` where `x` is a string of zeroes and ones not containing the pattern `01` anywhere.

The script gives the number of throws required to terminate two games, `01` and `11`, and these should have the same result since the coin is not a biased one (equal chance of outcome zero or outcome one on a toss).

Yet this is not the case, with my output being 6 and 4 respectively, of which only the first is correct. So I must have a bug in the script.

My questions are: how can I make the script a little more concise, as I hope this will help find the bug; and second, is there a bug that is apparent to all but me?

```
import numpy as np
class coin_series(object):
    def __init__(self,win_state):    #win_state is a string of ones and zeroes
        self.win_state=win_state
        self.d=self.draw()
        self.series=[self.d.next() for i in range(len(self.win_state))]
        self.n=len(self.win_state)
        while not self.check():
            self.play()
    def draw(self):
        while True:
            t=np.random.rand()
            if t>=0.5:
                yield 1
            else:
                yield 0
    def check(self):
        return(self.win_state==''.join(map(str,self.series)))
    def play(self):
        self.series=self.series[1:]+[self.d.next()]
        self.n+=1
if __name__=='__main__':
    print np.mean([coin_series('11').n for i in range(100000)])
    print np.mean([coin_series('01').n for i in range(100000)])
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a *two-player* game where a player wins if their sequence comes up first, who has the advantage is more complex than just whose sequence takes longer on average to come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no bug, your code works just fine!

As you toss the coins, if you are aiming for a `0` then a `1` and you make the `0` but the `1` ends up being another `0`, then you are still already halfway there, you are just hoping for a `1` again.

On the other hand, if you are aiming for a `1` and then a `1` and make the `1`, then if you don't make the second `1`, you are now on a `0` and back to waiting for a first `1`.

So to reword that a different way, in the first case, if you fail, you only get reset halfway, but in the second case, if you fail then you are back to the start again - thus increasing the average number of throws to get them.

Take a look at [this redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4abm4k/expected_number_of_coin_flips_different_for/) for another explanation.

Comment: Why did you edit your link out? Now you're telling people to look at nothing.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry! I mis-edited whilst writing an explanation!

Comment: This answers my question. I had an inadequate understanding of the game. Thank you very much. I found the link quite useful, but perhaps your explanation does away with needing to read it. Is the protocol now to tag this as an answer?

Comment: Yes! Click on the grey tick next to the answer and it will turn green, marking future visitors that this worked for you (so may work for them as well!)

Comment: Thank you. Any comments on making the script more compliant with best practice would be very useful too!

Answer (score 1):

No bug. You would need to be generating *separate pairs* of flips for those values to be equal. If you generate a continuous sequence of flips and look at overlapping pairs, `11` takes longer to come up on average than `01`.

Comment: Thank you, see above, you have made the game clearer to me. I would like to tag this as an answer but don't know how. Let me know if I am missing something, or if this comment closes the question. Thanks again!